# Sql to object, many to many with field

Tags: java, mysql, postgresql, object, uml

I am working on a little website. The database was created and we need to create objects from sql now.

Usually, in "Many to many" relation, I use a list to represent this relation. (List of ingredient in recipe, and if I need, a list of recipe in ingredient).
But I don't know what is the best way when the junction table contain field.

For example with theses tables:

```
######            ####################            ##########
RECIPE            INGREDIENT_IN_RECIPE            INGREDIENT
 id                  id_ingredient                  id
 name                id_recipe                      name
                     quantity
                     other
```

Is there a best way to create object from this sql?

I don't know if:

- I need to create an third object "IngredientInRecipe". And list it on recipe/ingredient?
- Maybe create fields quantity/other in ingredient and use it only when I want to handle ingredient as "ingredientinrecipe"?
- Or create a Subclass of Ingredient with quantity/other?

Maybe I'm totally wrong and I just have to create list in recipe and use sql query or array for other things but I'm little bit lost.

Comment: Generally the best way to create a "relation with properties" like this is to define a third entity which has a RECIPE and an INGREDIENT, as well as a members for any relational data. Then do it as two `OneToMany`/`ManyToOne` relationships

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple association class and you would model it like this:

[image]

You concrete object model with single tables it pretty fine.

Answer (score 0):

The answer here is based on the question is the `INGREDIENT_IN_RECIPE` an entity by itself, or is it just a relational table to create the many to many in the db.

Currently, `INGREDIENT_IN_RECIPE` contains additional information, that is really important and further specifies the relation between `RECIPE` and `INGREDIENT`, so this qualifies it is a proper entity.

IMHO, the best way here is to create a entity class for the `INGREDIENT_IN_RECIPE` table and list it on the `RECIPE` entity class at least. You need to check if the relation from the `INGREDIENT` entity is really needed and useful.